# Generic function to map JSON objects with ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, alamofire, objectmapper

I have a generic function:

```
   func toObjectMapper<T: Mappable>(mapper: T, success: (result: Mappable) -> Void, failure: (error: NSError) -> Void){
        let alomofireApiRequest = AlamofireApiRequest(apiRequest: self)
        Alamofire.request(alomofireApiRequest)
            .responseObject { (response: Response<T, NSError>) in
                guard let value = response.result.value else {
                    failure(error: response.result.error!)
                    return
                }
                success(result: value)
        }

    }
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
public func login(login: String, password: String) -> UserResponse {
        let params = ["email":login, "password":password]

        let request = ApiRequest(method: .POST, path: "login", parameters: params)

        request.toObjectMapper(UserResponse.self, success: { result in
                print(result)

            }, failure: { error in
                print(error.description)
        })
    }
```

But I always get this error:

```
 Cannot invoke 'toObjectMapper' with an argument list of type '(UserResponse.Type, success: (result: Mappable) -> Void, failure: (error: NSError) -> Void)'
```

This is my userResponse:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

public class  UserResponse: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var address = ""
    dynamic var zipcode = ""
    dynamic var city = ""
    dynamic var country = ""
    dynamic var vat = ""
    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var created_at = NSDate()
    dynamic var updated_at = NSDate()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    //Impl. of Mappable protocol
    required convenience public init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        id    <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        address <- map["address"]
        zipcode <- map["zipcode"]
        city <- map["city"]
        country <- map["country"]
        vat <- map["vat"]
        email <- map["email"]
        created_at <- map["created_at"]
        updated_at <- map["updated_at"]


    }
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use UserResponse as an instantiated object but using UserResponse.self is only the class type.

A solution is to make UserResonse a singleton (or just instantiate an instance before passing it to 'toObjectMapper' as an argument)

I don't know if this code specifically will work but it's along these lines:-

```
public class  UserResponse: Object, Mappable {
dynamic var id = 0
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var address = ""
dynamic var zipcode = ""
dynamic var city = ""
dynamic var country = ""
dynamic var vat = ""
dynamic var email = ""
dynamic var created_at = NSDate()
dynamic var updated_at = NSDate()

static let shared = UserResponse() //singleton instantiation

override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

//Impl. of Mappable protocol
required convenience public init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

public func mapping(map: Map) {
    id    <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    address <- map["address"]
    zipcode <- map["zipcode"]
    city <- map["city"]
    country <- map["country"]
    vat <- map["vat"]
    email <- map["email"]
    created_at <- map["created_at"]
    updated_at <- map["updated_at"]


}
}
```

and then in your function call

```
public func login(login: String, password: String) -> UserResponse {
    let params = ["email":login, "password":password]

    let request = ApiRequest(method: .POST, path: "login", parameters: params)

    request.toObjectMapper(UserResponse.shared, success: { result in
            print(result)

        }, failure: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
}
```

Comment: I did a quick test and it silenced the warning. So you need to instantiate an instance of UserResponse. The above is just a rough example as to how I would do it.